# Parsing C string

Tags: c, gps

I'm quite unfamiliar with C. A comma sepearted string comes in and I need to untangle it. Some bits correspond to numerical values, others to words etc.

Input

```
char str_in;

str_in = "$GPRMC,114353.000,A,6016.3245,N,02458.3270,E,0.01,0,A*69";
```

Output

```
#include <string.h>
float lat, lon, time;

time = 114353.000;
lat = 60+(1/60)*16.3245; //Conversion to decimal degrees
lon = 024+(1/60)*58.3270;
```

All the spacings remain unchanged. The section I have struggled with is extracting the first two/three digits from the latitude/longitude and treating them differently. Can anyone help?

Comment: I assume you have `char *str_in`? Is this homework? What is your current code so far?

Comment: Ah, NMEA. Just when I thought I'd escaped from work for the evening...

Comment: For what it's worth, some receivers can give different numbers of decimal places for those numeric fields. Doing so is not particularly standard, but then again since the NMEA standard is proprietary, there are _all sorts_ of variants out there. Long story short, _don't_ assume that each token will be of a fixed length.

Comment: For the benefit of everyone else, the lat/long fields have the format `ddmm.ssss`. The OP needs `dd + (mm.ssss / 60)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uses strtok. Here's a reference:

http://www.metalshell.com/source_code/31/String_Tokenizer.html

```
/* strtok example by mind@metalshell.com
 *
 * This is an example on string tokenizing
 *
 * 02/19/2002
 *
 * http://www.metalshell.com
 *
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int x = 1;
        char str[]="this:is:a:test:of:string:tokenizing";
        char *str1;

        /* print what we have so far */
        printf("String: %s\n", str);

        /* extract first string from string sequence */
        str1 = strtok(str, ":");

        /* print first string after tokenized */
        printf("%i: %s\n", x, str1);

        /* loop until finishied */
        while (1)
        {
                /* extract string from string sequence */
                str1 = strtok(NULL, ":");

                /* check if there is nothing else to extract */
                if (str1 == NULL)
                {
                        printf("Tokenizing complete\n");
                        exit(0);
                }
                /* print string after tokenized */
                printf("%i: %s\n", x, str1);
                x++;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

http://nmea.sourceforge.net/#features

Looks good.

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do something like this:

```
sscanf(str_in, %[^,],%f,%c,%f,%c,%f",
    command,
    &packed_time,
    &fix_status,
    &packed_lat,
    &NS,
    &packed_long);

struct lat_long { 
    int degrees;
    double minutes;
};

lat_long lat, long;
lat.degrees = packed_lat / 100;
lat.minutes = packed_lat - lat.degrees;

long.degrees = packed_long / 100;
long.minutes = packed_long - long.degrees;
```